# how to get value from datalist

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to get the value from the datalist?

Currently I get defined for the 2 parameter yoursign and friendsign

for example if I choose Aries for yoursign and Leo for friendSign I need to get both and pass to the function

```
    <body>
    <form id="Match"></form>

<label for="yourSignList">your sign:</label><br /><input list="yourSignList" name="sign1" required><br />
<datalist id="yourSignList">
    <option value="Aries">
    <option value="taurus">
    <option value="Gemini">
    <option value="Cancer">
    <option value="Leo">
    <option value="Virgo">
    <option value="Libra">
    <option value="Scorpio">
    <option value="Saggitarius">
    <option value="Capricon">
    <option value="Aquarius">
    <option value="Pisces">
</datalist>



<label for="friendSignList">your friend sign:</label><br /><input list="friendSignList" name="sign2" required><br />
<datalist id="friendSignList">
    <option value="Aries">
    <option value="taurus">
    <option value="Gemini">
    <option value="Cancer">
    <option value="Leo">
    <option value="Virgo">
    <option value="Libra">
    <option value="Scorpio">
    <option value="Saggitarius">
    <option value="Capricon">
    <option value="Aquarius">
    <option value="Pisces">
</datalist>



<button type='submit' onclick="Match()">Done</button><br>
<label for="output">התאמה: </label><output id='output'></output>
<form />

<script>
    function Match() {

      const signYours = $("yourSignList").val();
      const signFriend = $("friendSignList").val();

        $("#output").val(answer(signYours, signFriend));
    }
```

Comment: you don't get the value from the datalist, you get the value from the inputs.

Answer (score 0):

try this code may be working like

```
$("#friendSignList").find("option").each(function(e,i){
    console.log( e, i );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

this works for me:

```
   function Match() {
        var signYours = $("input[name='sign1']").val();
        var   signFriend = $("input[name='sign2']").val();

        $("#output").val(answer(signYours, signFriend));
    }
```